# Python-Pygame always crashing and Not Responding when running a module in IDLE

Tags: python, crash, pygame

I'm quite new to Pygame or even Python, but i know that when something in the isn't right, it displays some text in the Python Shell telling you that there was some error. I've actually encountered many of them and this time, it finally runs and displays the window, but it does not respond. I know there might be some mistakes in my whole code so please feel free to correct me (and please, kindly explain since I'm still new to this stuff).

The code is below, but if it can help, if you'd ask for it, i'll see if i could post the file as well. Anyway, here's the codes:

```
#import Modules
import os, sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

background_img="C:/Users/JM/Documents/Python/Pygame_Alpha/background_img.jpg"
cursor_img="C:/Users/JM/Documents/Python/Pygame_Alpha/pygameCursor.png"

def load_image(img_file, colorkey=None):
    file_pathname = os.path.join("\Users\JM\Documents\Python\Pygame_Alpha",img_file)

    try:
        image = pygame.image.load(file_pathname).convert_alpha()

    except pygame.error, message:
        print "Can't load image:", file_pathname
        raise SystemExit, message

    image = image.convert()

    if colorkey is not None:
        if colorkey is -1:
            colorkey = image.get_at((0,0))
    image.set_colorkey(colorkey, RLEACCEL)

    return image, image.get_rect()



#Main character's position and movements
char_x,char_y = 0,0
char_go_x,char_go_y = 0,0

#Main char class
class char(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
 """Main Character"""
     def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)#call Sprite initializer
        self.image, self.rect = load_image("char_img.png", -1)
        self.jumping = 0

    def update(self):
        self.rect.midtop = char_x,char_y
        if self.jumping == 1:
        self.rect.move_ip(-35,-3)


    def char_no_jump(self):
        self.jumping = 0

    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_caption("pygame_Alpha")
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,480),0,32)
    background = pygame.image.load(background_img).convert()
    cursor = pygame.image.load(cursor_img).convert_alpha()

    char = char()

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    millisec = clock.tick()
    sec = millisec/1000.0

    char_fall = sec*25
    jump = sec*50

    #blit the background
    screen.blit(background,(0,0))

    #Main Loop
    while 1:

       #Tell pygame not to exceed 60 FPS
       clock.tick(60)


       #Events
       for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            #Events triggered when a key/s is/are pressed
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w:
                    char.jumping = 1

                elif event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_s:
                    char_go_y += 1
                elif event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a:
                    char_go_x -= 0.5                
                elif event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d:
                    char_go_x += 0.75
                    if char_x > 800:
                        char_x = 0

            #Events triggered when a key/s is/are released
            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w:
                    char_go_y += 1
                elif event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_s:
                    char_go_y = 0
                elif event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a:
                    char_go_x = 0
                    if char_x < 0:
                    char_x = 0
                elif event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d:
                    char_go_x = 0
                    if char_x > 700:
                    char_x = 0

        char.update()
        while char_y < 200:
        char_go_y += char_fall

        if char_y > 200:
        char_y = 200

        #Update values of position of Main Char
        char_x += char_go_x
        char_y += char_go_y

        #Position Variables of Cursor Image, setting its values equal to cursor pos, and blit it to screen
        cursor_x,cursor_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        cursor_x -= cursor.get_width()/2
        cursor_y -= cursor.get_height()/2
        screen.blit(cursor,(cursor_x,cursor_y))

        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Can you fix formatting; really hard to where your loops begin and end but it looks like possibly you have a while loop that just does clock.tick(60)

Comment: And i also fixed the formatting, but i know it still quite a mess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm...

```
while char_y < 200:
           char_go_y += char_fall
```

Unless you have some interesting aliasing I'm not seeing, if char_y < 200 (which it should be at start, it will always be since you're updating char_go_y.

If that's not the issue, would still suggest adding some prints to figure out if it's getting through the loop or not.

Comment: Man, you're quite a genius! I found an error (although Python doesn't think it is) in my code which was because the value of char_y is 0 and that while loop says that: if char_x is less than 200 (which is always True, 0 WILL ALWAYS be <200), update value of char_go_y, making the loop itself like a recursive function. Thank you, man, my code still has this weird cursor image glitch and the char image still is won't show, but I think I would post that in another question since this question would be off topic to the one I asked here... Anyway thank you man, you solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

is there any error message in idle when you run it? whenever the screen freezes you have something wrong, but its hard to pinpoint what without knowing the error messages. maybe it is trouble opening the picture, you should try putting .convert() at the end of your picture file name, but that is just a guess.

Comment: and that's the weird thing because there is no text in the Python shell/IDLE, it just won't respond. How do I post screen shots in here? i'm a new user, too. I'm just 13 and am just starting to learn this whole stuff. and the .convert() stuff?! I have used either .convert() or .convert_alpha() in all the images that i loaded. .convert_alpha() is used so the "alpha" layer in images is shown transparent. Thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Calling pygame.quit and sys.exit are probably causing issues. Normally you'd never need them in pygame.

Instead of:

```
#Main Loop
while 1:

   #Tell pygame not to exceed 60 FPS
   clock.tick(60)


   #Events
   for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Do this

```
#Main Loop
done = False
while not done:
   clock.tick(60)

   for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESC:
                done = True
```